# Read table from MySQL - Python

Tags: python, mysql

I have MySQL ( Database: items, Table: issuelist )

I want to read and print out by python... but when I run code as below, it show error.

```
import mysql.connector
#from mysql.connector import Error

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
host="localhost",
#user="yourusername",
#passwd="yourpassword",
database="items"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql_statement = "SELECT * FROM issuelist"

mycursor.execute(sql_statement)
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()

for x in myresult:
print(x)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Chatbot - ReadData\ExcelMySQL.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       database="items"   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector__init__.py",
>   line 219, in connect
>       return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py",
>   line 104, in **init**
>       self.connect(**kwargs)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\abstracts.py",
>   line 960, in connect
>       self._open_connection()   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py",
>   line 292, in _open_connection
>       self._ssl, self._conn_attrs)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py",
>   line 212, in _do_auth
>       self._auth_switch_request(username, password)   File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py",
>   line 256, in _auth_switch_request
>       raise errors.get_exception(packet) mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied
>   for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

How to do resolve ?

Thanks you so much!

Comment: Don't you have any mysql user?
Try user="root"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite explanatory :

> Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)

You can't just connect to mysql with no account...

Comment: Thanks you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The error msg clearly shows the mistake --  The connect info is not correct. That is ,in your code, make sure the info of the host,user,passwd and database are all correct?